# Appcelerator : ImageView and local files

Tags: ios, path, imageview, titanium, appcelerator

for two days now, i have been looking for the correct place to put my local images and the correct way to access them in the Appcelerator platform (working with Alloy framework). 
All i want to do is simply display a local image through an image view component. It works well with an image get from URL but seems impossible to get it from a local file.

this is an simple image view declaration in my index.js controller
/app/controllers/index.js. Where do i have to put my image to get this code working?

```
var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
   image:'images/DefaultIcon.png',
   top:10,
   width:100,
   height:100
});
$.index.add(img);
```

I have read all the documentation about that issue and read a lot of similar questions over the internet. Anyway, none of the answers i've been reading bring me the correct solution.
No matter where i put my images into my project directory (assets folder, root folder, resource folder, image folder), those images seem to be not accessible ! 
I'm currently developing on iOS platform...
I really hope some of you guys have the solution ...!

Best regards,

Quentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the images in the `/app/assets/iphone/images` folder.

Within that folder you can create as many folders as you'd like, the only thing you need to do is update the path accordingly.

So, you have an image with the name `myIcon.png`. Put this in `/app/assets/iphone/images/myIcon.png` (and don't forget to include `@2x` and `@3x` images in the same folder).

Then, in your imageView use this path `/images/myIcon.png`.

Want to put it in a folder? For example `/app/assets/iphone/images/icons/myIcon.png` then reference it in an imageview with `/images/icons/myIcon.png`.

For android you too need to use the `images` folder inside `app/assets/android`. But to specify dimension specific images you can put them in `ldpi`, `mdpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi`,`xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` folders as specified by Android

Comment: Well, i have tried that already but it does not work..  here is a screenshot of my source tree, my code and the app render :
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=456055Capturedcran20161006143927.png

The image i want to display is the default icon of alloy tech, as you can see its not properly displayed..

Comment: I have a feeling you're not allowed to use that filename

Comment: Oups, my bad it's actually working ! 
Just needed to clean the project! 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as such!